# how to redirect certain urls from virtual Apache server to Tomcat

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat

I have a virtual Apache server on http://someserver:8013/ and I have Tomcat running that server.
How do I configure the redirects so that if i do "http://someserver:8013/tomcat/" then I will see the Tomcat's local host page, and "http://someserver:8013/tomcat/_appname" will be the apps deployed on Tomcat.

Comment: I had already solved similar task. See my answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/206540/absolute-urls-not-working-with-apache2-ajp-proxy-tomcat/304199#304199

Answer (score 0):

mod_proxy - 
See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

mod_jk can also be used (see http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html), but I believe that most folks are just using mod_proxy now.